# How to use only one specific time zone using javascript and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, momentjs

I have a web app that was created in PHP many years ago, and wanted to switch over to use Javascript and MongoDB as it's easier to scale the DB for changes over time.  The dates and times are killing me, though.  I've spent so much time trying to understand how it all works, and I feel like maybe I'm making things too complicated.

I have an office that is in the Eastern Time Zone.  All my appointment times are set times, and the zone does not change ever.  All my clients live in this time zone, and they would be scheduling by selecting an appointment time by clicking on a button associated with that time.

What do I need to do to:

1. save the appointment date and time to Mongo from ionic AND
2. display the retrieved appointment date and time from Mongo in the same time zone

I am even totally willing to just IGNORE time zone, if that is an option because I don't even care about the time zone.  Daylight savings doesn't matter, because it will always be 8AM on whatever day.  The time zone changing does not change the hour of the appointment.

Please help me with the most dumbed down version you have.  With or without moment.js (I've tried both and keep failing miserably).

[image: Client selects a time that is available]

Comment: So what's the problem if you save `Date` with timezone? Since all your clients live in the same timezone they will receive the same time values

Comment: Mongo saves the date as utc but when I display the times they are off by several hours.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo's officials documentation suggests saving timezone along with date information. Something like:

```
var now = new Date();
db.data.save( { date: now, offset: now.getTimezoneOffset() } );
```

Then you can reconstruct the original local time by applying the saved offset before you show the value:

```
var record = db.data.findOne();
var localNow = new Date( record.date.getTime() -  
    ( record.offset * 60000 ) );
```